# How to get rows having specified value in sql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like this -

```
id       cat_id
1        1,2
2        1,3
3        5,3,11
```

And I want to get count of those rows which have `cat_id = 1` (For Ex- in uppar case it count is 2). How can I do it ?

Comment: `select regexp_split_to_array(cat_id, ',')` and then you can count array

Comment: I would instead consider normalizing the tables.

Comment: Storing id's as comma seperated values is very bad db design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get count of `cat_id = 1`**

```
select count(*) 
from (
     select unnest(string_to_array(cat_id, ','))::int rowz
     from foo ) t
where rowz = 1
```

**To get all `cat_id` and it's *total count***

```
select rowz cat_id,count(*) total_count from (
select unnest(string_to_array(cat_id, ','))::int rowz
         from foo ) t 
group by rowz
order by cat_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE`, for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl 
WHERE cat_id LIKE '1,%'
```

*if string is starting from something different ??? like 5* asked by @POHH :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl 
WHERE cat_id LIKE '%,1,%'
   OR cat_id LIKE '1,%'
   OR cat_id LIKE '%,1'
```

Comment: I am using your query and it is giving me count = 3. It is taking cat_id with 11 also.

Comment: @POHH : I've updated the answer with your conditions.

Comment: @notulysses yup gotcha

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the comma separated list to an array and then use the `ANY` operator to search for the desired `cat_id` value:

```
select count(*)
from foo
where 1 = any (string_to_array(cat_id, ',')::int[])
```

But you should really consider fixing your data model. Storing comma separate lists is almost always a bad choice. *If* you have to de-normalize, using an array is the better choice in Postgres.